# What is the proper syntax to open a URL in a private window in Firefox when using the webbrowser module?

Tags: python

This works:

```
os.system("firefox --private-window https://www.example.com")
```

This works:

```
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('https://www.example.com')
```

This fails:

```
webbrowser.get('firefox --private-window').open('https://www.example.com')
```

What did I do wrong? I'm trying to open example.com in a private window using the webbrowser module.

I'm running Linux Mint 20.3.

Answer (score -2):

the `open()` function is for opening a file, not a webpage

e.g. `open("example.txt")` not `open("example.com")`

in the future, providing an error message would be helpful

Comment: You're thinking of a different `open`.